# How to use multiple arguments in ANY query when is bind message supplies parameters trhowing error?

Tags: postgresql, query, datatypes, errors

I have the following query that is using one parameter that contains a lot of valid values to validate with ANY, right now I need to cast the id from **bigint** to **int** and validate with integers (This is the initial error because I was trying to use IN). This query is for Postgres.

Script:

```
return `
  SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE  id::int = ANY(?::int[])
```

Print in the console

```
  SELECT *
  FROM users

  WHERE  id::int = ANY($1::int[])
```

This the error:

```
 Args: 8988,9939,7106,6019,3284,8356,5751,8192,4726,4911,9429,1892,3026,7726,10142,182,3318,3612,10835
 Error:
 error: bind message supplies 19 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1
```

In pgadmin, I can run the query, but I am not sure how to manipulate the arguments.

```
SELECT *
  FROM sites
  WHERE  id::int = ANY('{ 8988,9939 }')
```

Comment: Check this link out:[How to ask help about a query](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

In order to resolve the query I had use javascript map to transform the values in a list of parameters ($1, $2, $3 ...) instead of using a string that is reading as one parameter ($1), with the parameters list I am covering each paramenter (is working for dynamic parameters) to avoid these error: `bind message supplies 19 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1`

```
return `
  SELECT *
  FROM users
  WHERE  id::int = ANY(ARRAY[${parameters.map(() => '?::int').join()}])
```